# Google Place API (Place Details) will not allow GET request, work around

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

GET request intentionally by Google does not work on the Detailed Place JSON request, so i tried going round it by doing the following:

```
const detailedView = () => {
  const urlList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < search_place.length; i++) {
    urlList.push(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=${search_place[i].place_id}&key=${googleKey}`);
  }

  const scTag = document.getElementById('Detailed__Request');
        scTag.setAttribute('src', `${urlList[2]}`);
}

<script id="Detailed_Request" async defer></script>
```

So 'search_place' holds the list of objects that was returned by the places API, from there i pushing the link with the unique 'place_id' into an array 'urlList'.

Then as a test i'm manually add one of the url's to the script tag and that returns the JSON:

[image]

How can i actually access this data?

Any help will be appreciated :)

EDIT:

@Brett DeWoody (thanks for the reply)

So i just added the async GET request:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', urlList[2], true);
      xhr.send(null);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
```

I get the following error:

Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJabZ3FaUcdkgRoxxbahDO3bM&key=AIzaSyDqESELOJEOnNFFhWFsQG8fvuVAe_9WffM: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

After Googling that i found at that its intentionally being blocked.

Comment: Can you please share more of your code to help us understand the problem?  What do you mean the `GET` request does not work for the Detailed Place request?

Comment: Hi @BrettDeWoody thank you for the reply mate, please have a look at the main post again i made some changes for you to view.

Comment: Your error means you need to set up CORS on your server before any JS code on your site will be allowed to make requests to Google Maps.  Google is not intentionally blocking anything.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors

Comment: @Amy, aha thanks for that, ill have a look at the link you have left!